# iOS Undefined symbol: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSError._code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I made a category of `NSError` and I can't get ride of this compiler error:

> Undefined symbol: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSError._code

What I already did:

1. Clean.
2. Clean build.
3. Delete Derived Data.
4. Restart Xcode.
5. Search for similar questions.

**.h**

```
@import CloudKit;
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface NSError (CKErrors)

- (NSDictionary * _Nullable)getMergeRecords;


@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**.m**

```
#import "CKError+Bible.h"

@implementation NSError (CKErrors)

- (BOOL)isSpecificErrorCode:(int)errorCode {
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)_code);
    return YES;
}

@end
```

The error points to `NSLog` line, it uses the `_code` property of `NSError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `self.code`, not `_code`. Never attempt to access private ivars in a subclass or category. Only use the public properties and methods.